# Calling web api from ESP32 client

Tags: c++, asp.net-web-api, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm having trouble calling my asp.net web api from an esp32. I deployed my api to a remote IIS and I am able to call it from my computer (Chrome):

[image: API call from my computer]

But when I try to call the same URL from my esp32 I just receive -1 code:

[image: ESP32 serial monitor]

This is the arduino code I uploaded to the esp32:

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "HTTPClient.h"

const int32_t LED_BUILTIN = 2;

const char* SSID = "";
const char* PASSWORD = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("-");
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Wifi Connected");

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin("http://rmhq-routenet/testapi/weatherforecast");
    http.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    
    int response_code = http.GET();

    if(response_code > 0){
      Serial.print("Response Code: ");
      Serial.println(response_code);

      String response_data = http.getString();

      Serial.print("Response Data: ");
      Serial.println(response_data);
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Error Code: ");
      Serial.println(response_code);
    }

    http.end();
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

The SSID and PASSWORD are filled in, it does connect to my wifi.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The URL is not reachable for me.

Comment: I removed it since this is all testing, but it did work as I illustrated in the first picture. I'd like to know if there is anything wrong in my arduino code or if there might be something wrong in the way I deployed the api.

Comment: I see. Maybe the server is behind a NAT or requires some secure context to answer. I don't see anything wrong with this code at first sight.

Comment: Maybe you could try without the JSON header.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I tried it without the header and still got -1. I'll check your comment on the NAT thanks.

Comment: The NAT shouldn't be a problem since both the server and the esp32 is on the same network.

Comment: I got it working. For some reason if I call the server name then the api it does not work but if I replace the server name with it's ip address it works. It would seem that it was a NAT issue. Thanks for you input @Dr.Random